# timestamp, rowversion and datetime - I need a mark when a row is inserted or updated

Tags: sql, timestamp, rowversion

I have the following requirement:

I have a table with 1 unique auto-incremental Int ID and data columns.
I need the following:
Every time a row is inserted into that table, a column at the right end of the table must hold the full datetime of that insert.
Also, if a row is updated I need that column that holds the full datetime of the insert of that row into the table, to be updated to hold the update time for that row.

Now the obvious and very straightforward way to do this is:
you create your table:

```
create table My_Test_Table
(my_id int identity not null,
my_data nvarchar(max));
```

you alter your table adding the datetime column and a Default constraint on it:

```
ALTER TABLE My_Test_Table
ADD [timestamp] datetime;
ALTER TABLE My_Test_Table
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_My_Test_Table_timestamp DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR [timestamp];
```

then you make a nice trigger for update, like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DML_Trigger_update_My_Test_Table
ON My_Test_Table
FOR UPDATE
AS
IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
UPDATE My_Test_Table
SET [timestamp] = GETDATE()
FROM INSERTED
WHERE My_Test_Table.my_id = INSERTED.my_id;
END
END
```

Now the tricky part is:
I want, for reasons that are beyond scope here, to implement this exact thing as above but without a Trigger!
Is it possible?
I do not want to use the SQL type timestamp or rowversion, this won't work for me, I need the date, time down to the milliseconds to be clearly stored in that column.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a trigger

You can use the DEFAULT keyword as the source value in the UPDATE statement to use, well, the DEFAULT constraint defined on that column

```
UPDATE
   MyTable
SET
   foo = ...,
   bar = ...,
   ChangedDateTime = DEFAULT
WHERE
   ...;
```

I wouldn't use a column called [`timestamp` because this has meaning on SQL Server, as a synonym for `rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx). For SQL Server 2008+ use [`datetime2(3)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) to accurately record milliseconds. The "old" [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) is accurate to a rounded 3.33 milliseconds only

Comment: I am kinda used to the column name [timestamp] though I was aware of the above. It's just that Navision / Dynamics tables use it - ofc they use it with type timestamp, I use it with type datetime2 and I usually set a default constraint sysdatetime() (obviously not getdate() )